# Boostrap 4 : <a> in a <button>

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a `<a>` which is an icon that redirects to a page.
It  is inside a `<button>` and the `<button>` is a collapse button.
This `<a>` icon is inside the button so when I click on it, the menu is uncollapsing and THEN the link in my `<a>` is working.

My question is: Is there a way to "z-index" the `<a>` so when I click on it, the menu is not triggered while keeping the `<a>` inside the `<button>`.
If not, what do you suggest?

My code: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GaygNQ

Comment: do not put `<a>`-tags inside `<button>`-tags. This is really annoying and confusing for the user and also not easy to implement. If it is clickable it needs to be it's own element.

Comment: Take off the button and apply the redirect event straight to the icon, you can use JS if you want using `addEventListener("click", function{});`

Comment: But I need the button for the collapsing menu

Comment: And if I'm trying to put my <a> outside of my <button>, I'm struggling to place it correctly (on the same line, floating on the right)(https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GaygNQ)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this https://jsfiddle.net/gyd1to9z/
so `a` should be on his own element.
I edited your code a little bit from

```html
 <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
      <h2 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link text-left" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
          <a class="modificationUtilisateur" href="https://www.google.fr/" id="">
            <i class="fas fa-pen fa-pen-indicateur" title="Modifier"></i>
          </a>
        </button>
      </h2>
    </div>
```

to

```html
<div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
        <button class="btn btn-link text-left" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </button>
        <button class="btn btn-link text-right" >
          <a class="modificationUtilisateur" href="https://www.google.com/" id=""target="_blank">
            <i class="fas fa-pen fa-pen-indicateur" title="Modifier"></i>
          </a>
        </button>
    </div>
```

and in your css I deleted

```css
.fa-pen {
  float: right;
  z-index: 100000;
}
```

and replace it with

```css
#headingOne{
  display:flex;
}
```

hope this is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

According to W3C, the `<button>` element must only contain [phrasing content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Phrasing_content), not [interactive content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Interactive_content).
I simply suggest you to put your `<a>` outside of the `<button>` element and use flex layout.

Comment: Upvoted but note that `<a>` should not contain `<button>` elements either for the same reason.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap then why not use the `row` class so that the `<a>` is not inside the `<button>`

```
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-9">
         <button class="btn btn-link text-left" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
             Collapsible Group Item #1
         </button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <a class="modificationUtilisateur" href="https://www.google.fr/" id="">
            <i class="fas fa-pen fa-pen-indicateur" title="Modifier"></i>
        </a>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Something like this. Hope this help.